# Duplicate Key error, but not recreating when run with debug points

Tags: c#, ms-word, treeview, vsto, mvp

I am implementing a function to add some data to a tree view - MVP (application consists of Word ribbon (VSTO) + C# code base). Below is my code.

```
private ElementTreeNode LoadElement(Element element, ElementTreeNode parent = null)
{
    ElementTreeNode loadElement;
    ElementTreeNode node;

    //Add a node to the TreeView that represents the element.
    loadElement = Add(text: GetElementNodeText(element.Name), parent: parent);
    loadElement.Element = element;

    //Add a node to the TreeView for conditions
    if (element.TSS.Conditions.Count > 0)
    {
        Add(text: "Conditions", parent: loadElement).Conditions = element.TSS.Conditions;
    }

    //Add a node to the TreeView control for each image within the element.
    foreach (Image image in element.FrameSets.Active.Images)
    {
        Add(text: GetImageNodeText, parent: loadElement).Image = image;
    }

    //Call this procedure recursively to add any nested elements.
    foreach (Element objElement in element.FrameSets.Active.Elements)
    {
        LoadElement(element: objElement, parent: loadElement);
    }

    return loadElement;
}
```

Add method :

```
private ElementTreeNode Add(string text, string key = "", ElementTreeNode parent = null)
{
    try
    {
        TreeNode node = null;
        //Create a random key if a key is not specified.
        if (key.Length == 0)
        {
            key = "ElementTreeNode_" + GetRandomNumber();
        }

        //Add a node to the TreeView control.
        if (parent == null) //..............point 1
        {
            node = treeView.Nodes.Add(key: key, text: text);
        }
        else // ..............point 2
        {
            node = parent.Node.Nodes.Add(key: key, text: text);
        }
        //Add a new ElementTreeNode object to this collection. It will have the same key as objNode.
        ElementTreeNode objNode = new ElementTreeNode(node);                
        elementTreeNodesCollection.Add(key: key, value: objNode);

        return objNode;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "ElementTreeNodes.Add","MyApp,
                 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Create the random number :

```
public long GetRandomNumber()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return rnd.Next();
}
```

The issue is, in my test run
this code first add the parent element to the treeview and added into the collection (`Dictionary<string, ElementTreeNode> elementTreeNodesCollection`).  In the next step, a 'conditions' tree node will be added as a sub node under parent element to the tree node. When I try to add it to the `elementTreeNodesCollection`, it gives below error.

> An item with same key has already been added

The biggest issue is, if I put debug points at **point 1** or before (no other debug points in whole codebase) within Add method, I am not receiving any errors and items have been added to the tree view and collection well.

But if I add the debug point at or after **point 2**, I receive the error. Also when there are no break points, then also I got this error.

I tried setting the key as an incrementing number and then the code ran fine. But I need to use a random number here, as the LoadElement method involves with recursion.
Is this issue is related with the random number generating function? or other case?
I am really stuck in here.

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong in here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem is your `GetRandomNumber()` method, which depends on the current time. If you call it multiple times in quick succession, you'll end up getting the same number out of it.

If you wait a bit between calls - e.g. due to being paused at a breakpoint - you'll get different random numbers.

I'd suggest that the simplest option would be to make the number not random at all - keep a counter that you increment each time you need to create a new key. Or you could use `Guid.NewGuid()` and convert that to a string, or something similar.

If you really want to use `Random`, create a single instance of `Random` that you use for all the calls - but be aware that `Random` isn't thread-safe; if you need to do work across multiple threads, it all becomes a lot more complicated.